# How do I reference the object an anonymous class is declared in properly?

Tags: java, android, anonymous-class

I am assigning an OnClick listener to a View in Java as shown below:

```
public class MenuButton extends Fragment {
    MenuButton self = this;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                MenuButton button = self;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get the reference to the menu button and use it for something in my onTouch method (what for is irrelevant to the problem I think). I know I could call the methods of the class (e.g. getApplication()) but I specifically want the reference to the object the anonymous OnTouchListener is declared within.

As you can see I have found a solution though! The MenuButton self = this; line.

Is there a proper way of doing this or is my rather odd solution the only way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `MenuButton.this` to reference external class instance.

Answer (score 5):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    MenuButton button = MenuButton.this;
});
```

When inside an anonymous inner class, `this` refers to that anonymous class instance, so you have to explictly specify the outer class instance via `MenuButton.this`.

Answer (score 2):

You can always refer to the parent class in your enclosed anonymous class by using the

```
MyClass.this
```

syntax.

If something is unclear you can always refer to the official documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the official docs, always like to know where stuff like this is written down!